# Perl: read fifos non-blocking

Tags: perl, nonblocking

My original solution for https://superuser.com/questions/482953/read-non-blocking-from-multiple-fifos-in-parallel?answertab=oldest#tab-top saves a copy of the data on disk.

I have now made a second version that buffers a line in memory.

It works but it needs all fifos to be connected before it starts. This works:

```
window1$ mkfifo {1..100}
window1$ parcat {1..100} | pv >/dev/null

window2$ parallel -j0 'cat bigfile > ' ::: *
```

This does not give any output (because 100 is not connected):

```
window1$ mkfifo {1..100}
window1$ parcat {1..100} | pv >/dev/null

window2$ parallel -j0 'cat bigfile > ' ::: {1..99}
```

I tried using `open '+<'`. That solves the above problem, but now it does not stop at EOF.

How do I do that?

Minimal version (does not support big lines and does not backoff-wait):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Symbol qw(gensym);
use IPC::Open3;
use POSIX qw(:errno_h);
use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock);

for (@ARGV) {
    open($fh{$_},"<",$_) || die;
    # set fh non blocking($fh{$_});
    my $flags;
    fcntl($fh{$_}, &F_GETFL, $flags) || die $!; # Get the current flags on the filehandle
    $flags |= &O_NONBLOCK; # Add non-blocking to the flags
    fcntl($fh{$_}, &F_SETFL, $flags) || die $!; # Set the flags on the filehandle
}

while(keys %fh) {
    for(keys %fh) {
        my($string,$something_read) = non_blocking_read($_);
    print $string;
    }
    # Sleep 1 ms
    select(undef, undef, undef, 1/1000);
}

{
    my %buffer;

    sub non_blocking_read {

        my $file = shift;
        my $in = $fh{$file};
        my $rv = sysread($in, substr($buffer{$file},length $buffer{$file}), 327680);
        if (!$rv) {
            if($! == EAGAIN) {
            # Would block: Nothing read
            return(undef,undef);
            } else {
            # This file is done
            close $in;
            delete $fh{$file};
            my $buf = $buffer{$file};
            delete $buffer{$file};
            return ($buf,1);
            }
        }

        # Find \n for full line
        my $i = (rindex($buffer{$file},"\n")+1);
        if($i) {
            # Return full line
            # Remove full line from $buffer
            return(substr($buffer{$file},0,$i),
               1,substr($buffer{$file},0,$i) = "");
        } else {
            # Something read, but not a full line
            return("",1);
        }
    }
}
```

Full version: The important code is in the first 40 lines: The rest is well-tested code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Symbol qw(gensym);
use IPC::Open3;

for (@ARGV) {
    open($fh{$_},"<",$_) || die;
    set_fh_non_blocking($fh{$_});
}

$ms = 1;
while(keys %fh) {
    for(keys %fh) {
    my($string,$something_read) = non_blocking_read($_);
    if($something_read) {
        $ms = 0.1;
        print $string;
    }
    }
    $ms = exp_usleep($ms);
}

{
    my %buffer;
    my $ms;

    sub non_blocking_read {
    use POSIX qw(:errno_h);

    my $file = shift;
    my $in = $fh{$file};
    my $rv = read($in, substr($buffer{$file},length $buffer{$file}), 327680);
    if (!$rv) {
        if($! == EAGAIN) {
        # Would block: Nothing read
        return(undef,undef);
        } else {
        # This file is done
        close $in;
        delete $fh{$file};
        my $buf = $buffer{$file};
        delete $buffer{$file};
        return ($buf,1);
        }
    }

    #### Well-tested code below                                                           

    # Find \n or \r for full line
    my $i = (::rindex64(\$buffer{$file},"\n")+1) ||
        (::rindex64(\$buffer{$file},"\r")+1);
    if($i) {
        # Return full line
        # Remove full line from $buffer
        return(substr($buffer{$file},0,$i),
           1,substr($buffer{$file},0,$i) = "");
    } else {
        # Something read, but not a full line
        return("",1);
    }
    }
}

sub rindex64 {
    # Do rindex on strings > 2GB.
    # rindex in Perl < v5.22 does not work for > 2GB
    # Input:
    #   as rindex except STR which must be passed as a reference
    # Output:
    #   as rindex
    my $ref = shift;
    my $match = shift;
    my $pos = shift;
    my $block_size = 2**31-1;
    my $strlen = length($$ref);
    # Default: search from end
    $pos = defined $pos ? $pos : $strlen;
    # No point in doing extra work if we don't need to.
    if($strlen < $block_size) {
    return rindex($$ref, $match, $pos);
    }

    my $matchlen = length($match);
    my $ret;
    my $offset = $pos - $block_size + $matchlen;
    if($offset < 0) {
    # The offset is less than a $block_size
    # Set the $offset to 0 and
    # Adjust block_size accordingly
    $block_size = $block_size + $offset;
    $offset = 0;
    }
    while($offset >= 0) {
    $ret = rindex(
        substr($$ref, $offset, $block_size),
        $match);
    if($ret != -1) {
        return $ret + $offset;
    }
    $offset -= ($block_size - $matchlen - 1);
    }
    return -1;
}

sub exp_usleep {
    # Sleep this many milliseconds.
    # Input:
    #   $ms = milliseconds to sleep
    # Returns:
    #   $ms + 10%
    my $ms = shift;
    select(undef, undef, undef, $ms/1000);
    return (($ms < 1000) ? ($ms * 1.1) : ($ms));
}

sub set_fh_non_blocking {
    # Set filehandle as non-blocking
    # Inputs:
    #   $fh = filehandle to be blocking
    # Returns:
    #   N/A
    my $fh = shift;
    $Global::use{"Fcntl"} ||= eval "use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock); 1;";
    my $flags;
    fcntl($fh, &F_GETFL, $flags) || die $!; # Get the current flags on the filehandle
    $flags |= &O_NONBLOCK; # Add non-blocking to the flags
    fcntl($fh, &F_SETFL, $flags) || die $!; # Set the flags on the filehandle
}
```

Comment: can someone please explain to me the `close` vote? I don't quite understand how this doesn't fit...

Comment: Please try with sysread instead of read. sysread implements non-buffering read (i.e. similar to syscall read) while read implements buffered read and tries to read the full buffer (like fread). Also I recommend to use select to find out which file descriptor has data.

Comment: `eval "use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock); 1;"` makes no sense outside of a `BEGIN` block. Replace `$Global::use{"Fcntl"} ||= eval "use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock); 1;";` with `require Fcntl;`. [This isn't going to help with your problem.]

Comment: @stevieb, I imagine it's because they thought the question's code is far from a *minimal* demonstration of the problem. I know I won't be spending time on this when the OP isn't willing to.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich On my system `sysread` makes no difference. Did it work on your system? (I fought a full day getting `select` to work, and failed, so expect a follow up question when the EOF-problem is solved).

Comment: @OleTange: I agree that you should first produce a minimal example to demonstrate the problem. The code as it is is too complex to reproduce the problem. And remember to always `use strict` to eliminate the most trivial bugs, which is not the case with the code you have given.

Answer (score 3):

This solution opens a fake writer that is closed as soon as any data is received. It does the right thing except that it does not end if the input is empty:

```
mkfifo {1..100}
parcat {1..100} &
parallel -j2 echo works '>' {} ::: {1..100}

parcat {1..100} &
# Fails (parcat does not exit)
parallel -j2 cat /dev/null '>' {} ::: {1..100}
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    
use Symbol qw(gensym);
use IPC::Open3;
use POSIX qw(:errno_h);
use IO::Select;
use strict;

my $s = IO::Select->new();
my %fhr;
my %fhw;

for (@ARGV) {
    # Open the file with a fake writer that will never write
    open(my $fhw,"+<",$_) || die;
    # Open the file for real
    open(my $fhr,"<",$_) || die;
    set_fh_non_blocking($fhr);
    $s->add($fhr);
    $fhr{$fhr}++;
    $fhw{$fhr}=$fhw;
}

my %buffer;
while(keys %fhr) {
    for my $file ($s->can_read(undef)) {
        my $rv = sysread($file, substr($buffer{$file},length $buffer{$file}), 327680);
        if (!$rv) {
            if($! == EAGAIN) {
            # Would block: Nothing read
        next;
            } else {
            # This file is done
        $s->remove($file);
            delete $fhr{$file};
        print $buffer{$file};
            delete $buffer{$file};
        # Closing the $file causes it to block
        # close $file;
        next;
            }
        }
    if($fhw{$file}) {
        # We have received data from $file:
        # Close the fake writer
        close $fhw{$file};
        delete $fhw{$file};
    }
    
        # Find \n or \r for full line
        my $i = (::rindex64(\$buffer{$file},"\n")+1) ||
            (::rindex64(\$buffer{$file},"\r")+1);
        if($i) {
            # Print full line
            # Remove full line from $buffer
        print substr($buffer{$file},0,$i);
        substr($buffer{$file},0,$i) = "";
        next;
        } else {
            # Something read, but not a full line
        next;
        }
    }
}

sub rindex64 {
    # Do rindex on strings > 2GB.
    # rindex in Perl < v5.22 does not work for > 2GB
    # Input:
    #   as rindex except STR which must be passed as a reference
    # Output:
    #   as rindex
    my $ref = shift;
    my $match = shift;
    my $pos = shift;
    my $block_size = 2**31-1;
    my $strlen = length($$ref);
    # Default: search from end
    $pos = defined $pos ? $pos : $strlen;
    # No point in doing extra work if we don't need to.
    if($strlen < $block_size) {
        return rindex($$ref, $match, $pos);
    }
    
    my $matchlen = length($match);
    my $ret;
    my $offset = $pos - $block_size + $matchlen;
    if($offset < 0) {
        # The offset is less than a $block_size
        # Set the $offset to 0 and
        # Adjust block_size accordingly
        $block_size = $block_size + $offset;
        $offset = 0;
    }
    while($offset >= 0) {
        $ret = rindex(
            substr($$ref, $offset, $block_size),
            $match);
        if($ret != -1) {
            return $ret + $offset;
        }
        $offset -= ($block_size - $matchlen - 1);
    }
    return -1;
}

sub set_fh_non_blocking {
    # Set filehandle as non-blocking
    # Inputs:
    #   $fh = filehandle to be blocking
    # Returns:
    #   N/A
    my $fh = shift;
    $Global::use{"Fcntl"} ||= eval "use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock); 1;";
    my $flags;
    fcntl($fh, &F_GETFL, $flags) || die $!; # Get the current flags on the filehandle
    $flags |= &O_NONBLOCK; # Add non-blocking to the flags
    fcntl($fh, &F_SETFL, $flags) || die $!; # Set the flags on the filehandle
}
```

A better version of this is now distributed with GNU Parallel as `parcat`.

Comment: I was searching for `parcat` !